# Seekbar Thumbnails in MPC HC like Youtube

Tags: video, media-player-classic

I have downloaded the latest version of Media Player Classic Home Cinema which is v1.6.8.
I want to know if there is any way to generate "seekbar thumbnails" Like youtube?
I mean when I hover on seekbar it shows the small thumbnail of the scene
thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

this feature added to K-lite.
Changelog 15.9.0 to 15.9.5 ~ 2020-12-28

```
Updated MPC-HC to version 1.9.8.109
Updated LAV Filters to version 0.74.1-92-g88da5
Updated MPC Video Renderer to version 0.5.1.1584
Added option to MPC-HC to show a thumbnail preview on the seekbar
You can enable it during installation, or through: MPC-HC options > Tweaks > Show Preview on Seekbar
```

https://www.codecguide.com/changelogs_standard.htm

Comment: https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/issues/413

Answer (score 3):

The MPC has not this option, but MPC-BE, a MPC based program, has it. You can download it in:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe/

An other option is the Free Splash Lite, looked in: http://mirillis.com/en/products/splash.html

Good Luck